# django CMS 3.0 toolbar repeatedly shows login UI on some pages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am attempting to use the Django CMS toolbar in the following three contexts:

1. Pages created with django CMS, which have apphook set to none.
2. Pages created with django CMS, which have apphook set to Zinna.
3. Pages created outside of django CMS, which contain `static_placeholder`
   tags.

In case 1, I can log in using the django CMS toolbar, and subsequently see editing options. But in cases 2 and 3, I'm always presented with the login UI. If I enter my credentials into the toolbar, the page reloads and I see the login UI in the CMS toolbar again. If I log in using a bad username/password, I am giving an error by the toolbar.

The issues is that I am not seeing any errors, either in the js console in my browser, or in the Django log output. Could anybody tell me in which part of the django CMS stack I should begin to search?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by including `zinnia.urls` in our urls.py file. Our project uses the App Hook provided by [cmsplugin-zinnia](https://github.com/django-blog-zinnia/cmsplugin-zinnia#id15), but did not comment out our reference to `zinnia.urls`. So the django CMS toolbar was not processed correctly before the render path entered into the bowels of Zinnia.

The solution is to remove references to `zinnia.urls`, and use the Zinnia App Hook provided by cmsplugin-zinnia instead.